How to mocked chained global object in jest
I am trying to mock a database call but for some reason its not working. If I remove the .lean() its working find.
How to I mock this lean()
Below is my code
service.js
function getStoreData(storeId, callback) {
    global.models.Config.TransactionCashmgmtConfigModel.findOne({ storeId: storeId }).lean().exec((err, doc) => {
        if (!doc || err) {
            console.error('Error fetching document:', err);
            return callback(err, false);
        }

        console.log('Document found:', doc);
        return callback(null, true);
    });
}


test.js
global.models = {
    Config: {
        TransactionCashmgmtConfigModel: {
            findOne: jest.fn()
        },
    },
};

 describe('getStoreData', () => {
        it('should return store data', () => {
      
const mockData = {storeId: '1234', enabled: true};

            global.models.Config.TransactionCashmgmtConfigModel.findOne.mockImplementation(() => {
                return {
                    exec: (callback) => {
                        callback(null, mockData);
                    },
                };
            });

            getStoreData('1234', (err, data) => {
                expect(data).toEqual(mockData)
            });
        });
    });


Don't mock what you don't own. You end up writing very complicated test doubles that tell you your code continues to work even when the actual implementation needs to change.


You can use mockFn.mockReturnThis() to mock the chained method calls.

It can be seen from the assertions of the test, it should be callback(null, doc), not callback(null, true)

You forgot to call done(), see asynchronous#callbacks


e.g.
service.js:
function getStoreData(storeId, callback) {
  global.models.Config.TransactionCashmgmtConfigModel.findOne({ storeId: storeId })
    .lean()
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (!doc || err) {
        console.error('Error fetching document:', err);
        return callback(err, false);
      }
      console.log('Document found:', doc);
      return callback(null, doc);
    });
}

module.exports = getStoreData;

service.test.js:
const getStoreData = require('./service');

describe('getStoreData', () => {
  it('should return store data', (done) => {
    const mockData = { storeId: '1234', enabled: true };

    global.models = {
      Config: {
        TransactionCashmgmtConfigModel: {
          findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          lean: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          exec: jest.fn().mockImplementation((callback) => {
            callback(null, mockData);
          }),
        },
      },
    };

    getStoreData('1234', (err, data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
      done();
    });
  });
});

Test result:
  console.log
    Document found: { storeId: '1234', enabled: true }

      at log (stackoverflow/78278897/service.js:9:15)

 PASS  stackoverflow/78278897/service.test.js
  getStoreData
    √ should return store data (18 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.753 s, estimated 7 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

